# setting bounds for a constraint in CPLEX Concert Technology Java

Tags: java, linear-programming, cplex, operations-research

I am defining a constraint in a class and later I am calling that class. Now I want to define range for the constraint created. How to set upper bound for the constraint. Relevant part of the code only I have given below.

```
import ilog.concert.IloConstraint;
import ilog.concert.IloException;
import ilog.concert.IloIntVar;
import ilog.concert.IloLinearNumExpr;
import ilog.concert.IloNumVar;
import ilog.cplex.IloCplex;

import java.util.List;

public class ***** {

    public void model(IloCplex cplex, IloIntVar[] cccDecisionVariable, *****, int *****, List<*****> *****) throws IloException {
        IloLinearNumExpr constraintExpression = cplex.linearNumExpr();   
        constraintExpression.addTerm(cccc.getBbbb(),cccDecisionVariable[ccc.getCccId()];          

        IloConstraint constraint = cplex.addGe(constraintExpression,cccc.getAvailable());
        constraint.setName("gggg");             
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by an upper bound for the constraint? Do you mean adding another constraint to your model to provide an upper bound for the constraintExpression? If so, why not just add another constraint using cplex.addLe() or similar?

Comment: i was expecting to make a constraint like LB<=AX<=UB.
Defining another constraint with Less than will also work. Thanks Tim

Comment: LB<=AX<=UB is two separate constraints. You can write it down as one expression on paper, but in mathematical programming you must express it as two separate constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `IloRange` instead of `IloConstraint`

```
IloRange constraint = cplex.addGe(constraintExpression,cccc.getAvailable());
constraint.setUB(12.5);
```